# Sending mail to a group in postfix

Tags: linux, email, postfix-mta

I have a group named `users` and users `user1` and `user2`. I have postfix installed and I can get mail for `user1@example.com` and `user2@example.com`. Is it possible to send mail to `users@examlpe.com`, so group members are able to read it?

postfix is installed on ubuntu server and uses pretty much default config, just set the domains and networks and such. Users and groups are created with their home directories.

Comment: Please. Provide the work you have done so far

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the postfix manual:

```
# man aliases
...
 Aliases
  Local Aliases
     /etc/mail/aliases is formatted as a series of lines  of  the
     form

     aliasname:address[, address]


     aliasname is the name of  the  alias  or  alias  group,  and
     address  is the address of a recipient in the group. Aliases
     can be nested. That is,  an  address  can  be  the  name  of
     another  alias  group.  Because of the way sendmail(1M) per-
     forms mapping from upper-case to lower-case, an address that
     is  the  name  of  another  alias group must not contain any
     upper-case letters.

     Lines beginning with white space are treated as continuation
     lines  for  the  preceding alias. Lines beginning with # are
     comments.
```

You would need to manually add each user to the users group within the aliases file on your host (please check the manual for your distribution for that aliases file location).

So, for your given example:

```
# tail -1 /etc/mail/aliases
users: user1, user2
```

Once you have made these changes to your *aliases* file, run the following:

```
# newaliases
```